# Creating cab files on CF 2.0

Tags: compact-framework, cab

How to? 
what components do i need to have(platform builder?) ?

Please be as clear as possible - I find that this subject is very hazy and most people just give you a very vague answer.

I am running WInCE 5.0 with CF .net 2.0

Ultimately I need to create a self-updating application but I am going to start with creating a cab installer package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a cab file using the appropriate project type in Visual Studio. In Visual Studio 2005 select "Other Project Types", "Set up and deployment", "Smart device CAB project".

In a CAB file you can include executable and resource files. You can instruct where these files should be copied to. You can also add registry keys.

Comment: does a cab include dlls and exe?

Comment: ok, great! One more question: is it platform dependent? i don't have Platform Builder at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

This link actually helped me as well
http://www.mobilepractices.com/2008/02/how-to-create-windows-mobile-smart.html

great walkthrough on how to create cab files in Visual Studio 2008

Answer (score 0):

You can also checkout commercial softwares like Mobile Packager http://www.mobilepackager.com